# How do I set some text to bold in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, text, render, react-props

I know that how set some text bold like below.

```
<Text>I am<Text style={{fontWeight:bold}}>a developer</Text></Text>
```

But I need how use from props.

Example,

```
  <FlatList
          data={[{
            title: 'I am<Text style={styles.bold}>a developer</Text>',
            key: 'item1',
            id: 1
          }]}
          extraData={this.state}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
```

Title in FlatList is used in _renderItem.

```
<Text>this.props.title</Text>
```

But it's displayed on screen of device like below.

> `I am<Text style={styles.bold}>a developer</Text>`

The title in props is rendered just String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should pass a jsx to title prop :

```
title: {<Text>I am <Text style={{fontWeight:bold}}>a developer</Text></Text>}
```

Edit: If this is not working you can separate your title in 2 props :

```
<FlatList
    data={[{
      title: 'I am',
      titleBold: 'a developer'
      key: 'item1',
      id: 1
    }]}
    extraData={this.state}
    renderItem={this._renderItem}
 />
```

Then display it like this in _renderItem :

```
<Text>{this.props.title}<Text style={styles.bold}>{this.props.titleBold}</Text></Text>
```